# weak hopf conjecture

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, open-problems

I am thinking of the following problem which is related to the weak Hopf conjecture:

Let $E$ be the total space of a vector bundle over a compact nonnegatively curved manifold $B$. Let $k$ be the rank of $E$ and suppose that $k > \dim B$.
Now assume that $g$ is a complete metric on $E$ with non-negative sectional curvature.
By the soul theorem. there is a soul $N$ inside $E$. Also by a theorem of Guijarro and Walschap, for small $r>0$, the normal sphere bundle $N_r$ is also nonnegatively curved with respect to the induced metric of $g$.
Now the question is: Show this induced metric on $N_r$ can not have positive sectional curvature for all sufficiently small $r > 0$!
If $E$ is the trivial $\Bbb R^3$ bundle over $\Bbb S^2$, it is the so called "weak Hopf conjecture" Proposed by Gromoll and Tapp.

Is there anyone who knows any work on this problem?

Comment: But if I have some ideas about this, why would I want to share it on MathOverflow? Maybe you should ask your question a little differently and ask for recent work or progress on this question.

Comment: see Kris Tapp's recent paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1109.5150
